# SQL - a member can see a doctor only once a year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table named `Claim`.

[image]

I have built the following query except the last column(`Reimburse`). How do I populate `Reimburse` column like this table?

So the idea is that company pays a member to see a doctor only if it's been more than a year since his last "reimbursed" visit(reimburse = 1). `ClaimID C2` is denied because 10/10/2017 is less than 12 months from his last visit in 3/20/2017. `ClaimID C3` is approved because DOS is more than 12 months from his last APPROVED visit(C1) - even though it's been less than 12 months from his last (unapproved) visit (c2).

```
SELECT 
    MemberID,
    DOS,
    LAG(DOS,1,NULL) OVER (ORDER BY DOS) AS Last_DOS
FROM Claim
```

Sorry, if my question is confusing.

***DOS = date of service***

Comment: Which database you are using?

Comment: per year 1 service so just apply YEAR (DOS) if more than 1 service in a year make them zero otherwise keep it 1

Comment: I'm using sql server 11

Comment: @inincubus, try my answer. It will execute for all the members at a same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this below logic-

```
WITH CTE(claimid,memberid,dos)
AS
(
    SELECT 'C1', 7655,'20170320' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'C2', 7655,'20171010' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'C3', 7655,'20180430' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'C4', 7655,'20181121' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'C5', 7655,'20190531'
)

SELECT *,
CASE 
    WHEN LAG(dos) OVER (PARTITION BY memberid ORDER BY claimid)  > DATEADD(YY,-1,dos) THEN 0 
    ELSE 1 
END AS Reimburse
FROM CTE
```

Solution using CURSOR-

```
DECLARE 
@claimid VARCHAR(20),
@memberid INT,
@dos Date,
@reimbursed_dos_prev DATE = NULL,
@memberid_prev INT = NULL;


DECLARE @your_table TABLE(
    claimid VARCHAR(20),
    memberid INT,
    dos Date
);


INSERT INTO @your_table
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT 'C1' claimid, 7655 memberid,'20170320' dos UNION ALL
    SELECT 'C2', 7655,'20171010' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'C3', 7655,'20180430' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'C4', 7655,'20181121' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'C5', 7655,'20190531'
)A

DECLARE @your_table_2 TABLE(
    claimid VARCHAR(20),
    memberid INT,
    dos Date,
    Reimburse INT
);


DECLARE cursor_product CURSOR
FOR 
SELECT claimid,memberid,dos 
FROM @your_table
ORDER BY memberid,claimid;

OPEN cursor_product;

FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_product INTO @claimid,@memberid,@dos

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

        IF @reimbursed_dos_prev IS NULL AND @memberid_prev IS NULL
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @your_table_2(claimid,memberid,dos,Reimburse)
            VALUES(@claimid,@memberid,@dos,1)

            SET @reimbursed_dos_prev = @dos
            SET @memberid_prev = @memberid
        END

        ELSE IF @memberid_prev <> @memberid
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @your_table_2(claimid,memberid,dos,Reimburse)
            VALUES(@claimid,@memberid,@dos,1)

            SET @reimbursed_dos_prev = @dos
            SET @memberid_prev = @memberid
        END

        ELSE IF @dos < DATEADD(YY,1,@reimbursed_dos_prev)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @your_table_2(claimid,memberid,dos,Reimburse)
            VALUES(@claimid,@memberid,@dos,0)

            SET @memberid_prev = @memberid
        END

        ELSE 
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @your_table_2(claimid,memberid,dos,Reimburse)
            VALUES(@claimid,@memberid,@dos,1)

            SET @reimbursed_dos_prev = @dos
            SET @memberid_prev = @memberid
        END

        FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_product INTO @claimid,@memberid,@dos
    END;

CLOSE cursor_product;

DEALLOCATE cursor_product;

SELECT * FROM @your_table_2;
DELETE FROM @your_table_2;
```

Comment: Thank you but I only get Reimburse = 1 for ClaimID = C1.

Comment: I want C3 & C5 to be Reimburse = 1 even though C3's DOS is less than a year from C2, C2 was not reimbursed so it should compare C1's DOS.

Comment: Yes, as for other rows DOS is not greater than 1 year compare to previous DOS.

Comment: If I get your issue correct, you may then think about CURSOR

Comment: @inincubus, please check the  solution using CURSOR.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following answer. It will work for all the members.

**Table Schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE Claim(Claimid VARCHAR(5),MemberId VARCHAR(10),DOS DATETIME,Reimburse INT)

INSERT INTO Claim
    SELECT 'C1', 7655,'20170320',0 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'C2', 7655,'20171010',0 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'C3', 7655,'20180430',0 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'C4', 7655,'20181121',0 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'C5', 7655,'20190531',0 UNION ALL

    SELECT 'C1', 7657,'20170320',0 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'C2', 7657,'20171010',0 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'C3', 7657,'20180130',0 UNION ALL

    SELECT 'C4', 7658,'20181121',0 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'C5', 7658,'20190531',0
```

**SQL Query:**

```
SELECT *
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY MemberId ORDER BY DOS) RN 
    ,DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY MemberId) RNMember
INTO #Temp 
FROM Claim

DECLARE @MIN INT, @MAX INT, @IsReimburse DATETIME
DECLARE @MINMember INT, @MAXMember INT,@MemberID INT

SELECT @MINMember = MIN(RNMember),@MAXMember = MAX(RNMember) FROM #Temp

WHILE @MINMember<=@MAXMember
BEGIN

    SELECT @MemberID = MemberID FROM #Temp WHERE RNMember = @MINMember

    SELECT @MIN = MIN(RN),@MAX = MAX(RN) FROM #Temp WHERE MemberID = @MemberID

        WHILE @MIN<=@MAX
        BEGIN

          IF @MIN = 1
          BEGIN
            UPDATE #Temp
            SET Reimburse = 1 WHERE RN = 1 AND MemberID = @MemberID
          END
          ELSE
          BEGIN
            SELECT @IsReimburse = MAX(DOS) FROM #Temp WHERE Reimburse = 1 AND MemberID = @MemberID

            UPDATE #Temp SET Reimburse = CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY,@IsReimburse,DOS)>365 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
            WHERE RN = @MIN AND MemberID = @MemberID
          END

            SELECT @MIN = @MIN + 1

        END

    SELECT @MINMember = @MINMember + 1

END
```

**Update the temp table values to Your_table:**

```
UPDATE C
SET C.Reimburse = T.Reimburse
FROM #Temp T 
JOIN Claim C ON C.MemberID = T.MemberID AND T.Claimid = C.Claimid
```

**Output:**

```
Claimid     MemberId    DOS                     Reimburse
C1          7655        2017-03-20T00:00:00Z    1
C2          7655        2017-10-10T00:00:00Z    0
C3          7655        2018-04-30T00:00:00Z    1
C4          7655        2018-11-21T00:00:00Z    0
C5          7655        2019-05-31T00:00:00Z    1
C1          7657        2017-03-20T00:00:00Z    1
C2          7657        2017-10-10T00:00:00Z    0
C3          7657        2018-01-30T00:00:00Z    0
C4          7658        2018-11-21T00:00:00Z    1
C5          7658        2019-05-31T00:00:00Z    0
```